# How can I parse a 2D array in a query string?

Tags: jquery, scala, web-applications, playframework

I have the following jQuery call (which I can't change):

```
$.ajax({    url: "http://localhost/lookup-coord",
            jsonp: 'cb',
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            data: {'coord' : [[1,1],[1,2],[1,3]]},
            success: function(response) {
                console.log("Got the response: " + response);
            }
      });
```

My web application receives the following query string:

```
coord[0][]=1&coord[0][]=1&coord[1][]=1&coord[1][]=2&coord[2][]=1&coord[2][]=3
```

I want to know how I can parse that query string into an array in Scala Play. Is there an out of the box way to do this?

Comment: Probably it can be handled somehow, but I suggest you to modify sending data format. Take a look at [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rpuseywh/) to see what I mean.

Comment: @Regent I don't have control over the client Javascript code and can't make changes to it.

Comment: Well, then there is no need in mentioning `$.ajax` and tag `jquery` in question.

Answer (score 0):

Convert to array

```scala
scala>  val str = "coord[0][]=1&coord[0][]=1&coord[1][]=1&coord[1][]=2&coord[2][]=1&coord[2][]=3"
str: String = coord[0][]=1&coord[0][]=1&coord[1][]=1&coord[1][]=2&coord[2][]=1&coord[2][]=3

scala> val it = str.split("&").map(x => x.split("=")(1)).grouped(2)
it: Iterator[Array[String]] = non-empty iterator

scala> it.map(array => array.mkString("[",",","]")).mkString("[",",","]")
res0: String = [[1,1],[1,2],[1,3]]
```

Or:

```
scala> str.split("&").map(x => x.split("=")(1)).grouped(2).toList
res2: List[Array[String]] = List(Array(1, 1), Array(1, 2), Array(1, 3))
```

Answer (score 0):

Per my understanding you want query string to be like this:

```
http://localhost/lookup-coord/[[1,1],[1,2],[1,3]
```

A simple way is to use **JSON.stringify()**

```
var arr = [[1,1],[1,2],[1,3]];
$.ajax({    url: "http://localhost/lookup-coord",
        jsonp: 'cb',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        data: {'coord' : JSON.stringify(arr)},
        success: function(response) {
            console.log("Got the response: " + response);
        }
  });
```

You can use following link for reference: [MDN - JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

Answer (score -1):

If you want to send array to a given file (`http://localhost/lookup-coord` in this case ) 
probably the best think to do is something like the following :

```
// create empty array
var values = [];

// push the values

    values.push(1);
    values.push(2);

// when sending a parameter as an array we have to add [] after the name of the variable
```

we want to send and also wrap the variable name with single quotes 
for example (in this case )

```
$.post('file.php',{'var[]',values,another-var:val2},function(data){

console.log('this is the retrieved data from the target file');

});
```

the rule is simple
if you are using jquery `http request($.ajax,$.post,$.get)` then
if the variable is an array then do this
`'var-name[]':values`
else 
`var-name:single-value`